# Event handling using union hack c++

Tags: c++, function, events, pointers, unions

I have hot two classes. Assume that one of them is an Image and the other is a Page. The Image object receives an OnPointerPressed event and When it happens I would like to call a function form the Page calss. The problem is that this function is not defined until I pass the address of the member function to the image using union hack. When this method is called from the Image class it works fine but inside the method I can't see the Page Object and its members.

```
MainPage::MainPage(void)
{
    //.......
    image1->OnPointerPressedHandler->add(&MainPage::imageMousePressed);
}

void MainPage::imageMousePressed(STObject* sender, STPointerEventArg * args)
{
    void * dsda = this;  //the address of this is something wierd
    pres = true;
}
```

Can anybody help a little?

```
template<class T>
void add(T const & x)
{
    union hlp_t{
            void * v_ptr;
            T t;
    };
    hlp_t a;         
    a.t = x;
    functions->addLast(a.v_ptr);
}

template<class ARG>
void trigger(SENDERTYPE sender, ARG arg)
{
    STLinkedListIterator<void *>* it = functions->createIteator();
    if(it != nullptr)
    {
        do
        {
            void (*callback)(SENDERTYPE,ARG) =static_cast<void (*)(SENDERTYPE,ARG)>(it->getData());
            callback(sender,arg);
            /*
            void * myVoid = it->getData();
            __asm
            {
                push [arg];
                push [sender];
                call [myVoid];
            }
            */
            it->next();
        }while(!it->EOL());
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could include the union declaration, the code you are using to set it's values, and the code you are usnig to call the function in your question.

Comment: That looks like an overly confused attempt to pass a pointer to a member function. http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/pointers-to-members.html

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to use assembly language to call the member function. Please try to understand the features provided by the language first instead of attempting to implement a hack that you understand even less.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer Captain Obvlious. You only forget to mention that my hack actually works almost fine beside of I do have little understanding.

Comment: But just for you I commented out the assembly section and used c++ to call the function but my opinion is that is more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both the assembly language version and the non-assembly language version of your code you are calling the member function *incorrectly*. There are specific requirements for member functions that do not apply to calling a free function (and static member functions) which is exactly what both versions of your code are doing. When calling non-static member functions the `this` pointer is implicitly passed as the first parameter. This can be done by either pushing the pointer value onto the stack, placing it in a register, or both - it really depends on how the compiler generates the calling code.

The current version of your code attempts to call the member function as if it was a free function but passes the object pointer on the stack. This is a **very** bad idea and is the reason why the value of `this` is incorrect. It also may not work as you expect if `ARG` is an object being passed by value instead of by reference or pointer. This is because the entire object needs to be copied onto the stack - don't even try doing this yourself. Instead you should use the features provided by the language that are *specifically* intended to allow you to call member functions by pointer.

The syntax for a pointer to member function is `returntype (ClassType::*)(parameters)`. By using the correct syntax you can rely on the compiler to tell you when you use it incorrectly instead of trying to hunt down obscure bugs like you are currently doing. Not only should you use this when calling the member function but you should use it to store the pointer in your list. VC++ allows you to convert a function pointer to a void pointer but this is a Microsoft extension to the language and is **not** standard C++. I recommend you avoid the `void` whenever possible.

The one change you will *need* to make is how you are calling the member function. This is different than using a pointer to a free function and the following shows the correct syntax.

```
(objectpointer->*functionpointer)(arguments);
```

The extra set of parenthesis is required due to [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) and the `->*` is the "pointer to member" operator. The code below shows the changes you will need to make to your code to *correctly* call the member function.

```
template<class ARG>
void trigger(STObject* sender, ARG arg)
{
    STLinkedListIterator<void *>* it = functions->createIteator();
    if(it != nullptr)
    {
        do
        {
            // cast to a pointer to member function so the compiler knows
            // the correct type of the function call.
            void (STObject::*callback)(ARG)
                = static_cast<void (STObject::*)(ARG)>(it->getData());

            // call it using the correct syntax and let the compiler
            // handle all the gory details.
            (sender->*callback)(arg);

            it->next();
        }while(!it->EOL());
    }
}
```

You can make this more generic by adding an additional template parameter to specify the type of the target object.

```
template<class SENDER, class ARG>
void trigger(SENDER* sender, ARG arg)
{
    STLinkedListIterator<void *>* it = functions->createIteator();
    if(it != nullptr)
    {
        do
        {
            void (SENDER::*callback)(ARG)
                = static_cast<void (SENDER::*)(ARG)>(it->getData());

            (sender->*callback)(arg);

            it->next();
        }while(!it->EOL());
    }
}
```

## .

As a side note the function `add()` contains [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/845568). From $9.5/1 of the C++ Language Standard

> In a union, **at most one of the data members can be active at any time**, that is, the value of at most one of the data members can be stored in a union at any time.

In `add()` you set the value of `t` then read the value of `v_ptr`.

Comment: Ok this actually works fine but I would be pleased if you could give me a hint for the following problem. When I call the trigger function from the caller object I don't really know the type of the original class. I mean when I add the member function to the list I should also store the type of the object which could be solved by a generic linked list but I don't know the type before I actually add a new event. I don't know whether it is understandable or not. Pleas tell me it it isn't and I will try to be more clear.

Comment: Basically you create a common base class that all event receivers derive from and specify that as the type stored in the list _and_ the receiver argument passed to `add` instead of using `void*`. You just have to cast the function pointer when you pass it to `add` or change `add` to be template function and do the necessary casting there.

Comment: Since that's a separate issue post a new question if you need further clarification and I or someone else will surely provide a solution.

Comment: I created a generic example that should give you a better idea of what i'm talking about - [live example on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/I9BDtr)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the 'this' pointer as well to make this work, otherwise it would instantiate a separate instance of the class:

You have to modify the imageMousePressed like this:

```
// add in a void* argument    
void MainPage::imageMousePressed(STObject* sender, STPointerEventArg * args, void* mainPageObject)
    {
        MainPage* dsda = (MainPage*) mainPageObject; // now, you should have a pointer to the valid object
        pres = true;
    }
```

Now, this would mean the add function of OnPointerPressedHandler should also be modified to accomodate this:

```
    image1->OnPointerPressedHandler->add(&MainPage::imageMousePressed, this);
```

And internally it should pass call the pointed function passing the 'this' value. The reason this does not work now, if the function is instantiated like a static function which would then be a part of a new object, so the state of your old object would not be preserved.

PS: You should paste more code to give a better idea to folks who answer this

Comment: is there any way to call that function not as a static function but as member of the original class?

Comment: Not exactly, if you use function pointers. The proper design using OOP paradigms would be to pass in a pointer to the MainPage class. Define the function you want to call as a virtual function of the MainPage class (assuming there are subclasses that change the behavior) and then just call this function. That being said, I have seen many folks use the passing in for a void* parameter to allow to define a callback. HTH.

Comment: @dev_nut Passing an object pointer and dispatching through virtual functions is not always an option, especially when late binding on multiple objects is required which _seems_ to be the intent of the code in question. A better option for this particular scenario would be using `std::function` and `std::bind`. Using a pointer to member function is ok just not the most optimal solution.